# MeasureOverride available size is infinity

Tags: c#, exception, custom-controls

I have implemented a simple custom control in `UWP` platform. My problem is when I placed this control inside the `Hub` I got this error.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   been returned from a call to a COM component.    at
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)

Here `availableSize` width returns `infinity`, can anyone advise me how to resolve this problem?

```
<Hub>
    <HubSection>
        <DataTemplate>
            <myControl:MySimpleControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the custom control was added the children of `StackPanel`, throw the same exception. Because `StackPanel` width is infinity when `Orientation` is `Horizontal`. `HubSection` has also the same scenario like this.

So in this case have to allocated default(specific) Width for the control then call the `InvalidateMeasure()` to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error also comes up for scenarios involving `ListView` that has been changed to `Horizontal` orientation.
This is because `ListView` internally uses a `StackPanel` to arrange the items.

In general this issue can be avoided by arranging affected controls (Controls that are designed to fill the available horizontal space) within `Grid` or `GridView` instead of `StackPanel` or `ListView`